# how to add object on the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, tablemodel

Hello I am new to Java and I am practicing by creating a simple to do list app.

Everything works till now but I have a problem with 1 simple thing. How to print the values on my screen in a table form

```
       To Do     Date added
Delete nothing   1-1-2012
Delete something 2-2-2013
Delete test      3-2-2012
```

I already get every record in my console by doing a println

```
while(rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getInt("id") + "\n" + rs.getString("item") + "\n" + rs.getDate("datum"));
}
```

I have created this everything now with a MVC design but as you expect my VIEW is empty.. 
My question what is the best way to print this out on my JFrame with the help of the view?

Comment: Read the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). The basics first, and then probably the part about JTable. And be prepared: it's not "just a simple thing". You'll have to learn many things, and it'll take time.

Answer (score 3):

Populate a [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html), as in the following:

```
public class TodoModel extends DefaultTableModel {
    public TodoModel(ResultSet rs) {
        this.dataVector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
        for(rs.first();!rs.isAfterLast(); rs.next()) {
             Vector<String> row = new Vector<String>();
             row.add("Delete?");
             row.add(rs.getString(1));
             row.add(rs.getString(2));
             this.dataVector.add(row);
        }
        this.columnIdentifiers = new Vector<String>();
        this.columnIdentifiers.add("");
        this.columnIdentifiers.add("To Do");
        this.columnIdentifiers.add("Date added");
    }
}
```

Pass an instance of this to your [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) constructor and you should be golden. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: @Reshad: you won't be able to use Swing by copy 'n pasting code found on the Internet and not understanding how Swing works. Read the tutorial to know what a component is, how you lay out components, what a model is, what events and listeners are, etc.

Comment: @Reshad Also, as an adition to JB Nizet sentence, don't use any GUI designer like that in NetBeans or Windowbuilder Pro in Eclipse. Thats how I wasted like 6 months while "learning" Java swing.

Comment: This is your model, it's passed to your view (which in this case, would be a JTable, possibly within a JScrollPane, within a JFrame) as part of the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `System.out.println();` to print anything on frame. Use `JTable` instead:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;

public class Reshad {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Create frame
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                //Create table
                JTable table = new JTable();
                //Create table model (DefaultTableModel in this case)
                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{},new String[]{"To do","Date added"});
                //set model
                table.setModel(model);
                //To populate table call this method from model:
                model.addRow(new Object[]{"something","1-1-2012"});

                //Create scroll pane
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
                //Add scroll pane to center of your frame

                frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```